# AngularJS 2 call outside function in OnInit()

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

We create `AngularJS 2` application in `Asp.Net Core`. And used template is not support `AngularJS 2`. Problem is `Layout.Init()` function not initializing. I try call `Layout.Init()` function inside `OnInit()` event of `AngularJS 2` component. Then  I get error:

[image]

My code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ds-left-sidebar',
    template: require('./ds-left-sidebar.component.html')
})
export class LeftSidebarComponent implements OnInit {    
    ngOnInit() {
        Layout.init();
    }
}
```

Have any suggestion? Thanks for answers.

Comment: What is Layout here?

Comment: @micronyks, Layout is `javascript` function in `layout.js`

Answer (score 0):

Add declare in your code as follow:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare Layout:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'ds-left-sidebar',
    template: require('./ds-left-sidebar.component.html')
})
export class LeftSidebarComponent implements OnInit {    
    ngOnInit() {
        Layout.init();
    }
}
```

The declared `Layout` will be use the `Layout` object in layout.js.

hope this helps

Comment: I write `declare function Layout:any;` , in this case error occurred in `Layout.Init()`. `Init()` is not defined.

Comment: don't use the word "function" only "declare Layout:any;"